# ClassNotFound Exception when using Spring MVC 3.2.4 in multi-module maven project

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-social

I have a project which has the following structure:
  parent_module
    --common
    --persistence
    --service
    --web_ui
In the parent_module, I defined external project dependencies and properties, like spring-mvc, spring-social, spring-data, hibernate and etc. persistence module has entity definitions and repositories. All repositories extend from spring data JPARepository. Service module has a bunch of service definitions. Web_ui has all the web pages and Spring configurations. It is used for packaging WAR file as well.

All packages were in the same project based on one pom.xml file before. I am using spring java configuration. The project was working fine. However I decided to refactor it into different modules. Therefore, I move all persistence packages to persistence module and do the same for other packages.

However, after I moved them, spring container cannot start. It throws an error message saying **ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.SomeEntityRepo**

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.mycompany.persistence.repo",       repositoryImplementationPostfix="CustomImpl")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig{
.....
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    vendorAdapter
            .setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
    vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGE_TO_SCAN);
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml");
    factory.setPersistenceUnitName("persistenceUnit");

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties
            .setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class",
            "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");

    factory.setJpaProperties(properties);

    factory.afterPropertiesSet();

    return factory.getObject();
}
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface BookEntityRepo extends JpaRepository<BookEntity, Long>{
}
```

Thanks for any advice in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1-check project face (mainly jdk) ,use sts Markers to any contrast ,and change as your environment .

2-clean project ,In many case you need remove maven nature and add again after change project face

3-install and generate source again to target

4-set webserver run time again

Answer (score 0):

Well i would Recommend you to make configuration of Hibernate Properties and SessionFactory into the Spring Xml File and Try to check each Of jar files in  your Lib folder.
Actually i am not sure about this but this is causing due to the wrong jar files in your class path.